# How do I convert a String to its Enum value similar to Java's .valueOf?

Tags: vba, string-conversion

Given an enum:

```
Public Enum Options
    optionA
    optionB
    optionC
End Enum
```

and a String `myString = "optionB"`, is there a quick way to convert the String to the corresponding enum-value? (`Options.optionB` / `1`)

I.e. I'm looking for the VBA equivalent of Java's `.valueOf()`

I'm aware I could write a `Select Case`, but this is like writing the definition of the enum again and hard to maintain once the enum's values change.

Comment: Not in VBA, you'll have to build your own function to do that.

Comment: I don't think there's a more concise way than making your own function containing a `Select Case`. I usually make two: `OptionStringToEnum` and for the reverse operation `OptionEnumToString`. "*hard to maintain once the enums values change*" Sure, but code like `.valueOf("OptionC")` will be equally hard to maintain if OptionC changes. I don't see the relative benefit.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett You're right that **maintaining** `.valueOf()` would be difficult. That's why I asked for a way to code the `.valueOf()` without maintaing it. It is possible in Java, so I thought it might also be possible in VBA - but it seems it's not / pretty damn difficult.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**edited 2**: added solution #3 which

- has all the benefits of solution #2, i.e.

  - `valueOf` feature
  - single enum declaration (well, sort of...)
  - intellisense
- hasn't the drawback of needing (even if slightly) different names for Class and Enum (in solution #2 they were "OptionsC" and "Options")
- still bases on the VBE Object Model -> needs a few preliminary steps (see step 2))

---

solution #3

1)  add a Class module in your project, call it "EnumClass" (or whatever) and put in the following code

```
Option Explicit

Private Enums_ As Variant

Public optionA As String
Public optionB As String
Public optionC As String

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    optionA = "optionA"
    optionB = "optionB"
    optionC = "optionC"
    Enums_ = GetEnums
End Sub

Public Property Get valueOf(enumText As String) As Long
    Dim i As Long
    valueOf = -1
    For i = LBound(Enums_) To UBound(Enums_)
        If enumText = Enums_(i) Then
            valueOf = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Property

Private Function GetEnums() As Variant
    Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
    Dim lineCount As Long
    Dim strEnum As String

    Set CodeMod = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("EnumClass").CodeModule

    lineCount = 9 'if you keep class code as this one, you'd need checking lines from line 9. otherwise set it to 1 as a general setting
    With CodeMod

        Do Until InStr(UCase(.Lines(lineCount, 1)), UCase("Class_Initialize")) > 0
            lineCount = lineCount + 1
        Loop

        lineCount = lineCount + 1
        Do Until InStr(.Lines(lineCount, 1), "Enums_ = GetEnums") > 0
            strEnum = strEnum & GetTextWithingQuotes(.Lines(lineCount, 1)) & ","
            lineCount = lineCount + 1
        Loop
    End With
    GetEnums = Split(Left(strEnum, Len(strEnum) - 1), ",")

End Function

Private Function GetTextWithingQuotes(strng As String) As String
    Dim i1 As Long, i2 As Long

    i1 = InStr(strng, "=")
    i1 = InStr(i1, strng, Chr(34))
    i2 = InStr(i1 + 1, strng, Chr(34))
    GetTextWithingQuotes = Mid(strng, i1 + 1, i2 - i1 - 1)

End Function
```

2) do preliminary setting as per [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx) (see from "*In order to use the code on this page in your projects, you must change two settings*." to "***CAUTION***" clause included)

3) exploit it in your main sub as follows

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
Dim Options As New EnumClass '<== declare a variable of the EnumClass (or whatever the name you chose) and set it to a new instance of it
Dim myString As String

myString = "optionB"
MsgBox "string value of 'Options.optionB' = " & Options.optionB 'exploit intellisense
MsgBox "long Value of 'OptionB' =" & Options.valueOf(myString) 'convert the string to corresponding "enum" value

End Sub
```

---

here follows previous solution #2

1)  add a Module in your project, call it "OptionsModule" (or whatever) and place there your "Enum"

```
Public Enum Options
    optionA
    optionB
    optionC
End Enum
```

2) add a Class module in your project, call it "EnumClass" (or whatever) and put in the following code

```
Option Explicit

Private Enums_ As Variant

Public Property Let Enums(enumArr As Variant)
  Enums_ = enumArr
End Property

Public Property Get valueOf(enumText As String) As Long
    Dim i As Long
    valueOf = -1
    For i = LBound(Enums_) To UBound(Enums_)
        If enumText = Enums_(i) Then
            valueOf = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Property
```

3) add reference to "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility Library"

4) add this Function (in any module of your project)

```
Function GetEnums() As Variant
    Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject '<== this needs that reference to "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility Library"
    Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule '<== this needs that reference to "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility Library"
    Dim lineCount As Long
    Dim strEnum As String

    Set CodeMod = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("OptionsModule").CodeModule

    lineCount = 2
    With CodeMod
        Do Until InStr(UCase(.Lines(lineCount, 1)), UCase("End Enum")) > 0
            strEnum = strEnum & WorksheetFunction.Trim(.Lines(lineCount, 1)) & ","
            lineCount = lineCount + 1
        Loop
    End With
    GetEnums = Split(Left(strEnum, Len(strEnum) - 1), ",")

End Function
```

5) exploit it all in your main sub as follows

```
Sub main()
Dim OptionsC As New EnumClass '<== declare a variable of the EnumClass (or whatever the name you chose) and set it to a new instance of it
Dim myString As String

OptionsC.Enums = GetEnums() '<== fill your "Enum" class reading Module with enum

myString = "optionB"

MsgBox OptionsC.valueOf(myString) 'convert the string to corresponding "enum" value

End Sub
```

---

here follows previous solution #1

1) add a Class module, call it "EnumClass" (or whatever) and put in the following code

```
Option Explicit

Private Enums_ As Variant

Public Property Let Enums(enumArr As Variant)
  Enums_ = enumArr
End Property

Public Property Get valueOf(enumText As String) As Long
    Dim i As Long
    valueOf = -1
    For i = LBound(Enums_) To UBound(Enums_)
        If enumText = Enums_(i) Then
            valueOf = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Property
```

2) then in your main sub exploit it as follows

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
Dim Options As New EnumClass '<== declare a variable of the EnumClass (or whatever the name you chose) and set it to a new instance of it
Dim myString As String

Options.Enums = Array("optionA", "optionB", "optionC") '<== fill your "Enum" class with string values

myString = "optionB"

MsgBox Options.valueOf(myString) 'convert the string to corresponding "enum" value

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this good suggestion! Unfortunately this still requires me to write the values of the enum twice. I'd like to leave this question open for a little bit more to see if there is a better answer but will choose yours if none can be found.

Comment: Just to point out you have to write enum values only once: when you fill the class "Enums" property

Comment: Wouldn't I also need to write them first when defining the actual Enum? (Or miss out on some Features like intellisense)

Comment: With the "Enum" class you don't need real Enum at all. The former simply substitute the latter.

Comment: Substituting the enum would mean missing intellisense though. (The code-suggestion feature which suggests the values if you type code to set a variable with the Enum type)

Comment: If nothing else, this certainly is creative! Mind you, I'm not suggesting anyone should ever use this monstrosity :-)

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett: nor would I! But it's been funny and instructive for me and I took it just as a challenge driven by this especially peculiar OP needs.

Comment: Yup... I have a few old answers like that myself in the VBA tag. Good fun.

Answer (score 0):

I've an enum and created a function to convert strings to values because those aren't sequential:

```
Public Function IwoDates(idt_String As String) As Integer

Const idt_DteLen As Integer = 25, _
      idt_DteStr As String = "iwo_None                |iwo_Today               |iwo_Yesterday           |iwo_1Month              |iwo_EndMonth            |iwo_TodayToday          |" & _
                             "iwo_1MonthToday         |iwo_1Month1Month        |iwo_1MonthEndMonth      |iwo_1PastYear           |iwo_PastDays30          |iwo_PastMonth1          |" & _
                             "iwo_PastMonth2          |iwo_PastMonth3          |iwo_PastMonth1Today     |iwo_PastMonth2Today     |iwo_PastMonth3Today     |iwo_PastMonth1EndMonth  |" & _
                             "iwo_PastMonth2EndMonth  |iwo_PastMonth3EndMonth  |iwo_PastEndMonth        |iwo_Past1Month1Year     |iwo_PastYear1           |iwo_NextEndMonth        |" & _
                             "iwo_1Year               |iwo_1YearToday          |iwo_1YearEndMonth       |iwo_1Year1Year          |iwo_ComVentas           |iwo_FolioTkt            |", _
      idt_DteNum As String = "                       0|                      10|                      11|                      12|                      13|                      20|" & _
                             "                      21|                      22|                      23|                      24|                      30|                      31|" & _
                             "                      32|                      33|                      41|                      42|                      43|                      51|" & _
                             "                      52|                      53|                      61|                      62|                      63|                      71|" & _
                             "                      81|                      82|                      83|                      84|                      91|                      92|"

If Left(idt_String, 4) <> "iwo_" Then idt_String = "iwo_" & idt_String

IwoDates = Val(Mid(idt_DteNum, InStr(idt_DteStr, idt_String), idt_DteLen - 1))
```

End Function